# Dropdown menu works but only when I hover and not click

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My menu works but only when I hover and not click. It does not show up on mobile devices it only shows up as services but not clickable.

here is the code.

I believe I am missing something to make the dropdown box clickable ect.

```css
/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# General
--------------------------------------------------------------*/

body {
  background: #fff4e9;
  color: #444;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

a {
  color: #993300;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

a:hover,
a:active,
a:focus {
  color: #993300;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 30px 0;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* Back to top button */

.back-to-top {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  background: #993300;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 6px 12px 9px 12px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 15px;
  transition: background 0.5s;
}

.back-to-top:focus {
  background: #993300;
  color: #fff;
  outline: none;
}

.back-to-top:hover {
  background: #993300;
  color: #fff;
}


/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# Top Bar
--------------------------------------------------------------*/

#topbar {
  background: #fff4e9;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#topbar .contact-info a {
  line-height: 1;
  color: #555;
}

#topbar .contact-info a:hover {
  color: #993300;
}

#topbar .contact-info i {
  color: #993300;
  padding: 4px;
}

#topbar .contact-info .fa-phone {
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  border-left: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
}

#topbar .social-links a {
  color: #555;
  padding: 4px 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1px;
  border-left: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
}

#topbar .social-links a:hover {
  color: #993300;
}

#topbar .social-links a:first-child {
  border-left: 0;
}


/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# Header
--------------------------------------------------------------*/

#header {
  padding: 20px 0;
  height: 84px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  z-index: 997;
  background: #fff4e9;
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 9px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
}

#header #logo h1 {
  font-size: 42px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}

#header #logo h1 a {
  color: #993300;
  line-height: 1;
  display: inline-block;
}

#header #logo h1 a span {
  color: #993300;
}

#header #logo img {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}


/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# Intro Section
--------------------------------------------------------------*/

#intro {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60vh;
  position: relative;
  background: url("../img/intro-carousel/1.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

#intro .intro-content {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}

#intro .intro-content h2 {
  color: #993300;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-size: 64px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

#intro .intro-content h2 span {
  color: #993300;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#intro .intro-content .btn-get-started,
#intro .intro-content .btn-projects {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 32px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  margin: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}

#intro .intro-content .btn-get-started {
  background: #993300;
  border: 2px solid #993300;
}

#intro .intro-content .btn-get-started:hover {
  background: none;
  color: #993300;
}

#intro .intro-content .btn-projects {
  background: #993300;
  border: 2px solid #993300;
}

#intro .intro-content .btn-projects:hover {
  background: none;
  color: #993300;
}

#intro #intro-carousel {
  z-index: 8;
}

#intro #intro-carousel::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: );
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 7;
}

#intro #intro-carousel .item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition-property: opacity;
}


/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# Navigation Menu
--------------------------------------------------------------*/


/* Nav Menu Essentials */

.nav-menu,
.nav-menu * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-menu>li>.dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #fff4e9;
}

.nav-menu>li>.dropdown-item {
  background-color: #fff4e9;
}

.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover {
  background-color: #fff4e9;
  background-image: none;
}

.nav-menu ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}

.nav-menu li {
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.nav-menu>li {
  float: left;
}

.nav-menu li:hover>ul,
.nav-menu li.sfHover>ul {
  display: block;
}

.nav-menu ul ul {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}

.nav-menu ul li {
  min-width: 180px;
}


/* Nav Menu Arrows */

.sf-arrows .sf-with-ul {
  padding-right: 22px;
}

.sf-arrows .sf-with-ul:after {
  content: "\f107";
  position: absolute;
  right: 8px;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.sf-arrows ul .sf-with-ul:after {
  content: "\f105";
}


/* Nav Meu Container */

#nav-menu-container {
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
}


/* Nav Meu Styling */

.nav-menu a {
  padding: 10px 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #555;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 14px;
  outline: none;
}

.nav-menu li:hover>a,
.nav-menu .menu-active>a {
  color: #993300;
}

.nav-menu>li {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.nav-menu ul {
  margin: 4px 0 0 0;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(127, 137, 161, 0.25);
  background: #fff;
}

.nav-menu ul li {
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.nav-menu ul li a {
  padding: 10px;
  color: #333;
  transition: 0.3s;
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: none;
}

.nav-menu ul li:hover>a {
  color: #993300;
}

.nav-menu ul ul {
  margin: 0;
}


/* Mobile Nav Toggle */

#mobile-nav-toggle {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  margin: 20px 20px 0 0;
  border: 0;
  background: none;
  font-size: 24px;
  display: none;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#mobile-nav-toggle i {
  color: #555;
}


/* Mobile Nav Styling */

#mobile-nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  padding-top: 18px;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 998;
  background: rgba(52, 59, 64, 0.9);
  left: -260px;
  width: 260px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

#mobile-nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#mobile-nav ul li {
  position: relative;
}

#mobile-nav ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px 22px 10px 15px;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  outline: none;
}

#mobile-nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

#mobile-nav ul li li {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

#mobile-nav ul .menu-has-children i {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  padding: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
}

#mobile-nav ul .menu-has-children i.fa-chevron-up {
  color: #993300;
}

#mobile-nav ul .menu-item-active {
  color: #993300;
}

#mobile-body-overly {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 997;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  background: rgba(52, 59, 64, 0.9);
  display: none;
}


/* Mobile Nav body classes */

body.mobile-nav-active {
  overflow: hidden;
}

body.mobile-nav-active #mobile-nav {
  left: 0;
}

body.mobile-nav-active #mobile-nav-toggle {
  color: #fff;
}


/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# Sections
--------------------------------------------------------------*/


/* Sections Header
--------------------------------*/

.section-header {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.section-header h2 {
  font-size: 32px;
  color: #993300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.section-header h3 {
  font-size: 26px;
  color: #993300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.section-header h2::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #993300;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.section-header h3::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #993300;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.section-header p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}


/* About Section
--------------------------------*/

#about {
  padding: 60px 0 30px 0;
}

#about .about-img {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#about .about-img img {
  margin-left: -15px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

#about .content h2 {
  color: #993300;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
}

#about .content h3 {
  color: #555;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 26px;
  font-style: italic;
}

#about .content p {
  line-height: 26px;
}

#about .content p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

#about .content i {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-right: 4px;
  color: #993300;
}

#about .content ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

#about .content ul li {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}


/* Services Section
--------------------------------*/

#services {
  padding: 30px 0 0 0;
}

#services .box {
  padding: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 15px rgba(73, 78, 92, 0.1);
  background: #fff4e9;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

#services .box:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(73, 78, 92, 0.15);
  transform: translateY(-10px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-10px);
}

#services .box .icon {
  float: left;
}

#services .box .icon i {
  color: #444;
  font-size: 64px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  line-height: 0;
  margin-top: 34px;
}

#services .box .icon i:before {
  background: #993300;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #993300 0%, #993300 100%);
  background-clip: border-box;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

#services .box h4 {
  margin-left: 100px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-size: 22px;
}

#services .box h4 a {
  color: #444;
}

#services .box p {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  line-height: 24px;
}


/* Clients Section
--------------------------------*/

#clients {
  padding: 30px 0;
}

#clients img {
  max-width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: 0.3s;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

#clients img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

#clients .owl-nav,
#clients .owl-dots {
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

#clients .owl-dot {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#clients .owl-dot.active {
  background-color: #993300;
}


/* Our Portfolio Section
--------------------------------*/

#portfolio {
  background: #fff4e9;
  padding: 30px 0;
}

#portfolio .portfolio-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.4s;
}

#portfolio .portfolio-item {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

#portfolio .portfolio-item h2 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-weight: 700;
}

#portfolio .portfolio-item img {
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.4s;
  width: 100%;
}

#portfolio .portfolio-item:hover img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

#portfolio .portfolio-item:hover .portfolio-overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

#portfolio .portfolio-info {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


/* Testimonials Section
--------------------------------*/

#testimonials {
  padding: 30px 0;
}

#testimonials .testimonial-item {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  padding: 30px 30px 0 30px;
  margin: 30px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 350px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

#testimonials .testimonial-item .testimonial-img {
  width: 90px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#testimonials .testimonial-item h3 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 10px 0 5px 0;
  color: #111;
}

#testimonials .testimonial-item h4 {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #999;
  margin: 0;
}

#testimonials .testimonial-item .quote-sign-left {
  margin-top: -15px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 37px;
}

#testimonials .testimonial-item .quote-sign-right {
  margin-bottom: -15px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 37px;
}

#testimonials .testimonial-item p {
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 0 auto 15px auto;
}

#testimonials .owl-nav,
#testimonials .owl-dots {
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

#testimonials .owl-dot {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#testimonials .owl-dot.active {
  background-color: #993300;
}


/* Call To Action Section
--------------------------------*/

#call-to-action {
  background: #081e5b;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 40px 0;
}

#call-to-action .cta-title {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

#call-to-action .cta-text {
  color: #fff;
}

#call-to-action .cta-btn {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 26px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
}

#call-to-action .cta-btn:hover {
  background: #993300;
  border: 3px solid #993300;
}


/* Our Team Section
--------------------------------*/

#team {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 30px 0 0 0;
}

#team .member {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#team .member .pic {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

#team .member .pic img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

#team .member .details {
  background: #993300;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
}

#team .member h4 {
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#team .member span {
  font-style: italic;
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
}

#team .member .social {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

#team .member .social a {
  color: #fff;
}

#team .member .social i {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0 2px;
}


/* Contact Section
--------------------------------*/

#contact {
  padding: 30px 0;
}

#contact .contact-info {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

#contact .contact-info i {
  font-size: 48px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #993300;
}

#contact .contact-info address,
#contact .contact-info p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  color: #000;
}

#contact .contact-info h3 {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #999;
}

#contact .contact-info a {
  color: #000;
}

#contact .contact-info a:hover {
  color: #993300;
}

#contact .contact-address,
#contact .contact-phone,
#contact .contact-email {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#contact #google-map {
  height: 290px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#contact .form #sendmessage {
  color: #993300;
  border: 1px solid #993300;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#contact .form #errormessage {
  color: red;
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#contact .form #sendmessage.show,
#contact .form #errormessage.show,
#contact .form .show {
  display: block;
}

#contact .form .validation {
  color: red;
  display: none;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 13px;
}

#contact .form input,
#contact .form textarea {
  padding: 10px 14px;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#contact .form button[type="submit"] {
  background: #993300;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#contact .form button[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: #2dc899;
}


/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# Footer
--------------------------------------------------------------*/

#footer {
  background: #fff4e9;
  padding: 0 0 30px 0;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#footer .copyright {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

#footer .credits {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #555;
}

#footer .credits a {
  color: #993300;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #contact .contact-address,
  #contact .contact-phone,
  #contact .contact-email {
    padding: 20px 0;
  }
  #contact .contact-phone {
    border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 769px) {
  #call-to-action .cta-btn-container {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: end;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
    -ms-flex-pack: end;
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .back-to-top {
    bottom: 15px;
  }
  #header {
    padding: 20px 0;
    height: 74px;
  }
  #header #logo h1 {
    font-size: 34px;
  }
  #header #logo img {
    max-height: 40px;
  }
  #nav-menu-container {
    display: none;
  }
  #mobile-nav-toggle {
    display: inline;
  }
  #about .about-img {
    height: auto;
  }
  #about .about-img img {
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  #intro .intro-content h2 {
    font-size: 34px;
  }
  #services .box .box {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  #services .box .icon {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
  }
  #services .box h4,
  #services .box p {
    margin-left: 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
  #testimonials .testimonial-item {
    margin: 30px 10px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 576px) {
  #contact #google-map {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
}

#thumbnails {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#thumbnails ul li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 12px;
  margin-left: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav-menu-container">
  <ul class="nav-menu">
    <li class="menu-active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About us</a></li>

    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-item">Services</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="page1.html">page1</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="page2.html">page2</a></li>
      </ul>
      
         <li><a href="page3.html">page3</a></li>
        <li><a href="page4.html">page4</a></li>
         </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Menu dropdowns do not work on click. The dropdown shows only on hover and that is normal. Yours seems to be working on hover. What is not working for you?

Comment: Welcome @brendan. You are missing some default classes from bootstrap. please have a look at the bootstrap examples  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/#nav and compare your html

Comment: @MattOpen Just what i needed!. i have managed to compare and now i see what i did wrong :) Thank you

Comment: Still having issues!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers are right in front of you! @MattOpen sent you the Bootstrap nav components.
I am not going to do the work for you as you stated you was new to this so the best way to learn is to just get stuck in! make a copy so you can always revert and test.

Have a little look at this code below and then play around with you CSS :)`

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Services
    </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="page1.html">Dropdown Page 1</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="page2.html">Dropdwon Page 2</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="page3.html">page 3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="page4.html">page 4</a>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

`

Comment: Thanks i see what you mean with that code and the css i have fixed the issue and all is working cheers pal